# vuejs <router-link> component keeps the link to the root path always active

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I have my navigation like this

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
         <router-link tag="li" to="/"><a href="#">Home</a></router-link>
         <router-link tag="li" to="/page1"><a href="#">Page1</a></router-link>
         <router-link tag="li" to="/page2"><a href="#">Page2</a></router-link>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the link to Page1 to be active when ever am in page1 and same for Page2. It is working fine, the links are been activated when I navigate to the pages BUT the problem is that to link to the root (`/`) page is always active even when I leave the page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The root link is always active, because Vue Router partially matches the root `/` path with the current path.

To perform an **exact** match you can either:

1. Add an `exact` attribute to the `router-link`:

   ```
   <router-link tag="li" to="/" exact>
       <a href="#">
           Home
       </a>
   </router-link>
   ```
2. Set your active class in the [`linkExactActiveClass` router constructor option](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#linkexactactiveclass) instead of `linkActiveClass`.